# Batch processing_Distance to nearest hub

Tags: qgis-processing, batch

How do I go about batch processing for distance to the nearest hub? I have about 10 variables/covariates. Have tried severally and not seems to succeed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] you question to detail what you have tried, and it "not seems to succeed." Please also include the exact version of software in use in the question body.